# How can I intensify the chocolate flavour in my yoghurt?

Tags: flavor, chocolate, dessert, yogurt, additives

When I want a healthy dessert, I add grated dark (70%) chocolate to natural yoghurt. If I want some sweetness, I add dried cranberries. The cranberries definitely have a much stronger flavour, but even without them, the chocolate flavour does not come through very much. I think this is because it is designed to melt in your mouth before being eaten and the flavour only comes through when it melts. If it's in yoghurt, it's much too cold to melt.

Is there an additive or some alternative chocolate form (perhaps cocoa powder + something?) which could give a stronger chocolate flavour to yogurt which will be eaten cold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used powder as well, with good success. Syrup would definitely work. If you are grating chocolate, I suggest using a very fine grater such as a microplane.

Dried cranberries get most of their sweetness from added sugar.  Your better off flavor-wise to just add the sugar. For a more natural and healthful sweetener that is compatible with chocolate, I'd suggest date sugar or finely chopped dates.  Honey or maple syrup, as suggested in your first reply would also work.

Comment: I had no idea dried cranberries had added sugar! No wonder they taste so good...

Comment: @Ell cranberries are very bitter

Answer (score 2):

I almost do the same thing. I simply mix a scoop of cocoa powder into my *(usually vanilla flavored when I decide to add cocoa)* yogurt, and that's it.

But then again, I use sweetened yogurt, so maybe add some natural sweetener, like honey or maple syrup into your yogurt as well.